# how can i compare two array values

Tags: jquery

In Jquery how can i compare two array values. Below is my script

```
var corrAns = ['chBox_2','chBox_4','chBox_6','chBox_7','chBox_9'];
var userAns = new Array();

$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        var someObj = {};
        someObj.userAns = [];

        $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                someObj.userAns.push($(this).attr("id"));
            } else {

            }
        });

        alert( someObj.userAns);

    });
```

Thanks,
Sankar

Comment: Create a fiddle to get quick help but try jQuery inArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EGqL4/)

```
var corrAns = ['chBox_2', 'chBox_4', 'chBox_6', 'chBox_7', 'chBox_9'];

$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var userAnswers = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return this.id
    }).get().join(',');

    if (userAnswers === corrAns.join(',')) alert('Correct Answers!');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if 2 simple arrays (containings strings or numbers, not objects) are identical you can do:

```
array1.sort().toString() === array2.sort().toString()
```